# Converting Base64 to GMP integer

Tags: c, base64, gmp

I have a scenario where the I get a Base64 (64 bit encoded) string. My requirement is to convert this string to gmp integer (mpz_t).

But according to  [GMP manual](http://gmplib.org/manual/Assigning-Integers.html#Assigning-Integers)  only "The base may vary from 2 to 62" for the function mpz_set_str() .

Is there any approach I can follow to perform a successful conversion?
One idea that struck me was to convert the Base64 to binary and then set the mpz_t variable using mpz_set_str with base 2.

Help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is not the same as a number in base 64.

Comment: @lhf: Applying a base64 decode converts it to binary or a byte array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GMP bases are not the same thing as base64 encoding. You're on the right track - apply the base64 decode, then use `mpz_import` on the result.

Comment: @crazyscot: Thanks, another doubt, after Using the base64_Decode we convert it to a binary form. How does the result of mpz_import differ from that of mpz_set_str with the base as 2?

Comment: mpz_set_set reads from a printable string, in base 2 it may only contain "0" and "1" characters. mpz_import takes a binary input (byte array), though you have to make sure to set its parameters correctly for the format the number is in.

Comment: @crazyscot: So i am guessing base64 generally converts the encoding into a byte array?

Comment: base64 encoding turns a byte array into a printable string, typically for transmission over a medium like email; decoding is the exact opposite. The encoded string is usually made up from the characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+' and '/'; it comes out approximately 4/3 the size of the input string.

Comment: @crazyscot: the base64 decoding as you had suggested, will convert the byte array back to the printable string form which can be of the form "byte array" which can be used as the input for mpz_import?

Comment: base64 decoding turns a printable string into a byte array (not necessarily printable), which is what you want to pass to mpz_import.